# How to create a minimal APPX package

Tags: visual-studio, appx

The specific requirement is to create a test case for application deployment, so the appx itself doesn't have to contain a functional application - a stub library would suffice.

The problem I have is that a minimal "hello world" UWP application has a couple of dependencies on other libraries. For the scenario I want, the dependencies add unnecessary complexity and points of confusion and/or failure, and I seem to be unable to remove those dependencies from the app.

I can create a UWP library, but it appears to have the same non-removable dependencies as an application.

There are packages (Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00 and Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 for example) which are typical dependencies of other packages, but themselves have no dependencies. These libraries represent the sort of package I want to create for my test case.

How can I create such a package myself?